# Error: Cannot find module 'aws-sdk' in NodeJS AWS Lambda Function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I am trying to access `S3` via `aws-sdk` in my lambda function.

```
import S3 from 'aws-sdk/clients/s3';

const s3 = new S3();
const { Contents: results } = await s3.listObjects({ Bucket: process.env.DOCUMENTS_BUCKET_NAME! }).promise()
```

I have also deployed it successfully using `cdk deploy` command. But when I test, I get the following error

```
2022-11-23T15:53:40.891Z    undefined   ERROR   Uncaught Exception  
{
    "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
    "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module 'aws-sdk'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/index.js\n- /var/runtime/index.mjs",
    "stack": [
        "Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'aws-sdk'",
        "Require stack:",
        "- /var/task/index.js",
        "- /var/runtime/index.mjs",
        "    at _loadUserApp (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1000:17)",
        "    at async UserFunction.js.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1035:21)",
        "    at async start (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1200:23)",
        "    at async file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1206:1"
    ]
}
```

As per the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda_nodejs-readme.html#externals), `aws-sdk` is always available in the runtime.

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much

Comment: Based on the fact that your code is calling the legacy `listObjects` method rather than `listObjectsV2` and is using the `.promise()` feature, you appear to be trying to use JavaScript SDK v2, so `const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new AWS.S3();`

Comment: Or use SDK v3 as documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/index.html).

Answer (score 36):

If your lambda runtime is nodejs18.x my understanding is that SDK v2 is not included in the runtime.

So, the best solution would be to switch to v3 SDK https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/

Or, as a workaround in the short term if you use webpack and usually exclude bundling aws-sdk with the following:

```
externals: {
    'aws-sdk': 'aws-sdk'
},
```

Then simply leave externals out of your webpack.config.js and it will be bundled, but will of course make your lambda larger so not ideal

Or use nodejs16.x or below in the short term

Comment: using nodejs16.x fix my problem.  But I don't know why. Obviously, the same code worked at nodejs18.x before. do runtime nodejs18.x remove SDK v2 now?

Comment: Link to AWS Blog about this change regarding Node 16 vs Node 18 and its supported AWS SDK version: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/node-js-18-x-runtime-now-available-in-aws-lambda/

Answer (score 9):

**UPDATED LINK**

Thank you @jarmod, I needed the following dependency

```
@aws-sdk/client-s3
```

My commit with the fix is available [here](https://github.com/hhimanshu/typescript-cdk-samples/blob/main/lambda-s3-document-fetch-api/src/functions/getDocuments/package.json#L17)

Comment: The link for the commit is broken

Comment: @SteffiKeranRaniJ, I updated the link. Hope that helps

Answer (score 5):

For those using serverless framework with esbuild, the plugin excludes 'aws-sdk' by [default](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-esbuild#configuration). In my case, I didn't downgrade to v16, I kept v18 and put an empty array in my serverless.yml

```
custom:
  esbuild:
    exclude: []
```

Comment: Thank you! I missed that esbuild excluded `aws-sdk` by defualt.

Comment: It should be noted that doing this will inflate your bundle and (depending on your usage plan) could be more costly.

Answer (score 2):

What I did to fix this issue was to just downgrade my runtime settings from Node.js 18 to Node.js 16.x or below. After that, the test went successful.

Comment: Node.js 18 has numerous security enhancements, downgrading should be a last resort.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this problem.
I picked Node.js v18 when creating Lambda.
It was giving me the same error. But changing the package to "@aws-sdk/*" new versions solved the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

For those struggling with the Lambda upgrade from Node 16 to 18+, I kept getting this error until I did the following:

1. Update Runtime from Node 16 to Node 20
2. Update the code to `import` instead of `require` targeting the module that I needed `import { SESClient, SendEmailCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-ses";` in my case (and other code changes as needed based on updated import)
3. Rename the `index.js` file to `index.mjs`
4. The tests kept failing, but after publishing the function they succeeded.

Obviously, this is pretty risky, publishing prior to successful test, so you should try this in a qa environment or with an unused function first.